# Does git stash stash all changes or just uncommitted ones

Tags: git

If I stash changes using git, will it only stash uncommitted files, or will it stash everything that hasn't been pushed to git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that Git will stash everything which has not been *committed* to your local branch.

When you do a `git stash`, it actually makes *two* temporary commits.  The first one contains the files which you have staged (i.e. by doing `git add` on them).  The second one actually contains your working directory files.

When you do a `git stash apply`, Git will reinstate the working directory.  However, if you do `git stash apply --index`, then it will *also* try to reinstate the index (i.e. your staged files).

So `git stash` cleans the slate, and leaves both your stage and working directory in the state they were at your most recent commit.

Answer (score 1):

It will stash the dirty state of your working directory, specifically tracked files that have been modified and changes that have been staged but not yet committed.

It is not necessary to save committed files since, well, they've been committed. So if, by "pushed to git", you mean local commits that have been pushed to a mirror/origin repo, they won't be saved either (because they've already been committed).

Answer (score 0):

From the `git stash` documentation:

> Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory – that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes – and saves it on a stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time. [Source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning)